# Escape HTML using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, escaping

I came up with a hack to escape HTML using jQuery and I'm wondering if anyone sees a problem with it.

```
$('<i></i>').text(TEXT_TO_ESCAPE).html();
```

The `<i>` tag is just a dummy as jQuery needs a container to set the text of.

Is there perhaps an easier way to do this? Note that I need the text stored in a variable, not for display (otherwise I could just call `elem.text(TEXT_TO_ESCAPE);`).

Thanks!

Comment: What do you exactly mean by “escape HTML”? Do you want to convert characters like `<`, `>` and `&` to their corresponding HTML entities?

Comment: your example could be shortened to: `$('<i>').text(TEXT_TO_ESCAPE).html();`

Answer (score 62, accepted):

That's a pretty standard way of doing it, my version used a `<div>` though:

```
return $('<div/>').text(t).html();
```

This isn't technically 100% safe though as Mike Samuel notes but it is probably pretty safe in practice.

The current Prototype.js does this:

```
function escapeHTML() {
    return this.replace(/&/g,'&amp;').replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;');
}
```

But it used to use the "put text in a div and extract the HTML" trick.

There's also [`_.escape` in Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#escape), that does it like this:

```
// List of HTML entities for escaping.
var htmlEscapes = {
  '&': '&amp;',
  '<': '&lt;',
  '>': '&gt;',
  '"': '&quot;',
  "'": '&#x27;',
  '/': '&#x2F;'
};

// Regex containing the keys listed immediately above.
var htmlEscaper = /[&<>"'\/]/g;

// Escape a string for HTML interpolation.
_.escape = function(string) {
  return ('' + string).replace(htmlEscaper, function(match) {
    return htmlEscapes[match];
  });
};
```

That's pretty much the same approach as Prototype's. Most of the JavaScript I do lately has Underscore available so I tend to use `_.escape` these days.

Comment: A lot of libraries do this.  Just be aware that the result here is safe to embed in a PCDATA context and an RCDATA context, but not an attribute context since quotes are not escaped.  If you might be susceptible to UTF-7 attacks and the like you should also escape '+': http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-7#Security

Comment: @Mike: I don't think the `.text(t).html()` or Prototype's `replace` approaches are really that great, both approaches have problems. The lack of a `encodeHTML()` function in the standard JavaScript library is a gaping hole and a rather surprising oversight.

Comment: @muis: I don't think so: the core JavaScript language is not specifically aimed at web browsers.

Comment: @Marcel: But we do have `encodeURIComponent` and JavaScript's roots are in web browsers. And, the fact that everyone ends up writing their own indicates that there is a gap in the standard libraries.

Comment: @muis Thanks for the pointer to Prototype. It turns out that my proposed method doesn't work as I expect in some browsers (read: IE)

Comment: @Michael: Which IE version screws it up? I haven't noticed any problems but that doesn't mean there aren't any.

Comment: IE8. It actually mostly works. Perhaps this is expected behaviour, but newlines were stripped from the string which was returned.

Comment: @Michael: You can't really depend on whitespace being preserved unless you're using `<pre>` blocks but, as usual, whatever works.

Comment: Fortunately when working with a string, it's safe to just do the replacing. I was thrown at first because FF and Chrome seem to preserve whitespace just fine.

Comment: For those interested in the relative performance of the different approaches, you can see the results at: http://jsperf.com/encode-html-entities In essence, the regular expression approach appears to be the general winner, closely followed by the multiple replace() approach. However, the regular expression approach probably scales better than replace() if you escaping more than the basic three: &,<,>

Answer (score 11):

There is no guarantee that `html()` will be completely escaped so the result might not be safe after concatenation.

`html()` is based on `innerHTML`, and a browser could, without violating lots of expectations, implement `innerHTML` so that `$("<i></i>").text("1 <").html()` is `"1 <"`, and that `$("<i></i>").text("b>").html()` is `"b>"`.

Then if you concatenate those two individually safe results, you get `"1 <b>"` which will obviously not be the HTML version of the concatenation of the two plaintext pieces.

So, this method is not safe by deduction from first principles, and there's no widely followed spec of `innerHTML` (though HTML5 does address it).

The best way to check if it does what you want is to test corner cases like this.

Comment: Actually, I want `$("<i></i>").text("1 <").html()` to be `"1 &lt;"` and `$("<i></i>").text("b>").html()` to be `"b&gt;"`. (which works)

Comment: @Michael, if you've tested it on major browsers, and it works, great.  As of 15 June, 2009, a current version of Safari actually **unescaped** &gt; so `<input name="Hello&gt;World">` was returned via `innerHTML` as `<input name="Hello>World">`.  That may have been fixed in modern browsers though.  My point is that testing is the way to gain confidence.

Answer (score 1):

That should work. That's basically how the Prototype.js library does it, or at least how it used to do it.  I generally do it with three calls to ".replace()" but that's mostly just a habit.