# Is there an easy way to convert text into HTML in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Escaping HTML strings with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery)
>   [JavaScript/jQuery HTML Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/javascript-jquery-html-encoding)

For example, if I wanted to show the user the string `x < 3` in HTML I would need to replace the `<` character with `&lt;`.  Is there a prebuilt function to do this in JavaScript or perhaps jQuery that converts any text string into the corresponding HTML?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020714/escape-html-using-jquery

Comment: 10 answers ... can I get another 2 close votes, please?

Comment: 10 answers... must be an easy one.

Comment: Not duplicate because the question is about JavaScript, not Jquery

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use jQuery, you can use the `text(string)` method.

```
$(".selector").text("x < 5");
```

http://api.jquery.com/text/

Answer (score 4):

Or, Take it simple and do this

```
var str1 = "x < 3";
str1.replace(/</g, '&lt;');
```

Here is a [function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7124052/295264) from another question

```
function htmlEscape(str) {
    return String(str)
            .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
            .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
            .replace(/'/g, '&#39;')
            .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
            .replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}
```

Or, Excellent cheat using jQuery [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1219983/295264)

```
function htmlEncode(value){
  return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
}

function htmlDecode(value){
  return $('<div/>').html(value).text();
}
```

Comment: But this doesn't generalize to all dangerous text characters.  It only deals with the case of '<'.

Comment: @Dejas, I have update my answer. Please review

Answer (score 3):

With jQuery perhaps you do not have to html encode your text:

```
$("div.test").text("<b></b> for bold!");
```

sets the inner html of the div to:

```
&lt;b&gt;&lt;/b&gt; for bold!
```

You can then retrieve this html using:

```
$("div.test").html();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery power:

```
var str = "x < 3";
str = $('<div>').text(str).html();
```

Will give you `"x &lt; 3"` result. The string `"Alpha & Omega"` will become `"Alpha &amp; Omega"`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

let's say you have stored the string into a variable

```
k = " <!"#$\'";
```

then when you need to "print" the values use

```
escape (k );
```

Comment: And the string `'x < 3'` will become `x%20%3C%203`.

Comment: escape() is good for network transports, not for display. < will be translated into %3C, not & lt;

Answer (score 0):

There is a php function name htmlentities, I found this for JS :

```
function HTMLentities(texte) {

texte = texte.replace(/"/g,'&quot;'); // 34 22
texte = texte.replace(/&/g,'&amp;'); // 38 26
texte = texte.replace(/\'/g,'&#39;'); // 39 27
texte = texte.replace(/</g,'&lt;'); // 60 3C
texte = texte.replace(/>/g,'&gt;'); // 62 3E
texte = texte.replace(/\^/g,'&circ;'); // 94 5E
texte = texte.replace(/‘/g,'&lsquo;'); // 145 91
texte = texte.replace(/’/g,'&rsquo;'); // 146 92
texte = texte.replace(/“/g,'&ldquo;'); // 147 93
texte = texte.replace(/”/g,'&rdquo;'); // 148 94
texte = texte.replace(/•/g,'&bull;'); // 149 95
texte = texte.replace(/–/g,'&ndash;'); // 150 96
texte = texte.replace(/—/g,'&mdash;'); // 151 97
texte = texte.replace(/˜/g,'&tilde;'); // 152 98
texte = texte.replace(/™/g,'&trade;'); // 153 99
texte = texte.replace(/š/g,'&scaron;'); // 154 9A
texte = texte.replace(/›/g,'&rsaquo;'); // 155 9B
texte = texte.replace(/œ/g,'&oelig;'); // 156 9C
texte = texte.replace(//g,'&#357;'); // 157 9D
texte = texte.replace(/ž/g,'&#382;'); // 158 9E
texte = texte.replace(/Ÿ/g,'&Yuml;'); // 159 9F
// texte = texte.replace(/ /g,'&nbsp;'); // 160 A0
texte = texte.replace(/¡/g,'&iexcl;'); // 161 A1
texte = texte.replace(/¢/g,'&cent;'); // 162 A2
texte = texte.replace(/£/g,'&pound;'); // 163 A3
//texte = texte.replace(/ /g,'&curren;'); // 164 A4
texte = texte.replace(/¥/g,'&yen;'); // 165 A5
texte = texte.replace(/¦/g,'&brvbar;'); // 166 A6
texte = texte.replace(/§/g,'&sect;'); // 167 A7
texte = texte.replace(/¨/g,'&uml;'); // 168 A8
texte = texte.replace(/©/g,'&copy;'); // 169 A9
texte = texte.replace(/ª/g,'&ordf;'); // 170 AA
texte = texte.replace(/«/g,'&laquo;'); // 171 AB
texte = texte.replace(/¬/g,'&not;'); // 172 AC
texte = texte.replace(/­/g,'&shy;'); // 173 AD
texte = texte.replace(/®/g,'&reg;'); // 174 AE
texte = texte.replace(/¯/g,'&macr;'); // 175 AF
texte = texte.replace(/°/g,'&deg;'); // 176 B0
texte = texte.replace(/±/g,'&plusmn;'); // 177 B1
texte = texte.replace(/²/g,'&sup2;'); // 178 B2
texte = texte.replace(/³/g,'&sup3;'); // 179 B3
texte = texte.replace(/´/g,'&acute;'); // 180 B4
texte = texte.replace(/µ/g,'&micro;'); // 181 B5
texte = texte.replace(/¶/g,'&para'); // 182 B6
texte = texte.replace(/·/g,'&middot;'); // 183 B7
texte = texte.replace(/¸/g,'&cedil;'); // 184 B8
texte = texte.replace(/¹/g,'&sup1;'); // 185 B9
texte = texte.replace(/º/g,'&ordm;'); // 186 BA
texte = texte.replace(/»/g,'&raquo;'); // 187 BB
texte = texte.replace(/¼/g,'&frac14;'); // 188 BC
texte = texte.replace(/½/g,'&frac12;'); // 189 BD
texte = texte.replace(/¾/g,'&frac34;'); // 190 BE
texte = texte.replace(/¿/g,'&iquest;'); // 191 BF
texte = texte.replace(/À/g,'&Agrave;'); // 192 C0
texte = texte.replace(/Á/g,'&Aacute;'); // 193 C1
texte = texte.replace(/Â/g,'&Acirc;'); // 194 C2
texte = texte.replace(/Ã/g,'&Atilde;'); // 195 C3
texte = texte.replace(/Ä/g,'&Auml;'); // 196 C4
texte = texte.replace(/Å/g,'&Aring;'); // 197 C5
texte = texte.replace(/Æ/g,'&AElig;'); // 198 C6
texte = texte.replace(/Ç/g,'&Ccedil;'); // 199 C7
texte = texte.replace(/È/g,'&Egrave;'); // 200 C8
texte = texte.replace(/É/g,'&Eacute;'); // 201 C9
texte = texte.replace(/Ê/g,'&Ecirc;'); // 202 CA
texte = texte.replace(/Ë/g,'&Euml;'); // 203 CB
texte = texte.replace(/Ì/g,'&Igrave;'); // 204 CC
texte = texte.replace(/Í/g,'&Iacute;'); // 205 CD
texte = texte.replace(/Î/g,'&Icirc;'); // 206 CE
texte = texte.replace(/Ï/g,'&Iuml;'); // 207 CF
texte = texte.replace(/Ð/g,'&ETH;'); // 208 D0
texte = texte.replace(/Ñ/g,'&Ntilde;'); // 209 D1
texte = texte.replace(/Ò/g,'&Ograve;'); // 210 D2
texte = texte.replace(/Ó/g,'&Oacute;'); // 211 D3
texte = texte.replace(/Ô/g,'&Ocirc;'); // 212 D4
texte = texte.replace(/Õ/g,'&Otilde;'); // 213 D5
texte = texte.replace(/Ö/g,'&Ouml;'); // 214 D6
texte = texte.replace(/×/g,'&times;'); // 215 D7
texte = texte.replace(/Ø/g,'&Oslash;'); // 216 D8
texte = texte.replace(/Ù/g,'&Ugrave;'); // 217 D9
texte = texte.replace(/Ú/g,'&Uacute;'); // 218 DA
texte = texte.replace(/Û/g,'&Ucirc;'); // 219 DB
texte = texte.replace(/Ü/g,'&Uuml;'); // 220 DC
texte = texte.replace(/Ý/g,'&Yacute;'); // 221 DD
texte = texte.replace(/Þ/g,'&THORN;'); // 222 DE
texte = texte.replace(/ß/g,'&szlig;'); // 223 DF
texte = texte.replace(/à/g,'&aacute;'); // 224 E0
texte = texte.replace(/á/g,'&aacute;'); // 225 E1
texte = texte.replace(/â/g,'&acirc;'); // 226 E2
texte = texte.replace(/ã/g,'&atilde;'); // 227 E3
texte = texte.replace(/ä/g,'&auml;'); // 228 E4
texte = texte.replace(/å/g,'&aring;'); // 229 E5
texte = texte.replace(/æ/g,'&aelig;'); // 230 E6
texte = texte.replace(/ç/g,'&ccedil;'); // 231 E7
texte = texte.replace(/è/g,'&egrave;'); // 232 E8
texte = texte.replace(/é/g,'&eacute;'); // 233 E9
texte = texte.replace(/ê/g,'&ecirc;'); // 234 EA
texte = texte.replace(/ë/g,'&euml;'); // 235 EB
texte = texte.replace(/ì/g,'&igrave;'); // 236 EC
texte = texte.replace(/í/g,'&iacute;'); // 237 ED
texte = texte.replace(/î/g,'&icirc;'); // 238 EE
texte = texte.replace(/ï/g,'&iuml;'); // 239 EF
texte = texte.replace(/ð/g,'&eth;'); // 240 F0
texte = texte.replace(/ñ/g,'&ntilde;'); // 241 F1
texte = texte.replace(/ò/g,'&ograve;'); // 242 F2
texte = texte.replace(/ó/g,'&oacute;'); // 243 F3
texte = texte.replace(/ô/g,'&ocirc;'); // 244 F4
texte = texte.replace(/õ/g,'&otilde;'); // 245 F5
texte = texte.replace(/ö/g,'&ouml;'); // 246 F6
texte = texte.replace(/÷/g,'&divide;'); // 247 F7
texte = texte.replace(/ø/g,'&oslash;'); // 248 F8
texte = texte.replace(/ù/g,'&ugrave;'); // 249 F9
texte = texte.replace(/ú/g,'&uacute;'); // 250 FA
texte = texte.replace(/û/g,'&ucirc;'); // 251 FB
texte = texte.replace(/ü/g,'&uuml;'); // 252 FC
texte = texte.replace(/ý/g,'&yacute;'); // 253 FD
texte = texte.replace(/þ/g,'&thorn;'); // 254 FE
texte = texte.replace(/ÿ/g,'&yuml;'); // 255 FF
return texte;
}
```

Comment: This looks like it would work, but I think it might be too time consuming.

Comment: I'm agree, this is a full package to answer at the question.

Answer (score 0):

This replaces the characters in javascript:

```
function replaceStr(str) {
  return str
      .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
      .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
      .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
      .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
      .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use part of the php.js library which implements functions known from php to js. There's also famous `htmlspecialchars`: http://phpjs.org/functions/htmlspecialchars:426
Obviously, remove unnecessary parts from the function :)

Also take a look: [HtmlSpecialChars equivalent in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787322/htmlspecialchars-equivalent-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, you could do as this answer suggests:

[HTML-encoding lost when attribute read from input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/javascript-jquery-html-encoding)