# How to keep the spacing of text input from an HTML textarea

Tags: javascript, html

My process so far is:

1. Take text input into a form's `textarea` (often, an email with spaces, linebreaks, and perhaps special characters)

   ```
   <label for="sample">Sample:</label><br>
   <textarea id="sample" rows="4" cols="50" style="white-space: pre;">
   ```
2. Output it in the rendered webpage using javascript.

   ```
   function generate() { 

     var sample = document.getElementById("sample").value;
     //get the pasted in text with spaces and linebreaks from the text area

     var message = "<p><br> <b>Sample text:</b> More text, html formatting " + sample + " </p>";
     //make a variable with html formatted text and the sample text

     document.getElementById("pagetext").innerHTML = message;
     //show the message var text by overwriting the "pagetext" placeholder on the screen when user clicks button.

   }
   ```

Right now spacing and line breaks are not kept.

For example with Input `\nText`

The output is: `Text`

How do I keep the spacing and formatting while using HMTL text areas and Javascript?

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216805/is-there-an-easy-way-to-convert-text-into-html-in-javascript

Comment: If you are wanting to preserve multiple spaces and line breaks, what about the <pre> tag? If you could place your output in a <pre> tag then it should preserve what you want preserved.