# Append HTML-escaped text: jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, escaping

I'm used to using jQuery's `.append()` method to add text or HTML onto the end of a pre-existing element.  I'm currently using jQuery's `.text()` to escape strings that could potentially contain HTML.  Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a jQuery method that will append the results of the `.text()` method to an element instead of replacing its contents.

Is there a way to append, instead of replace, this escaped text to an element?  Or is there a better way to escape strings containing HTML?

Thanks.

**- EDIT -**

A little more context:  I'm building an HTML string dynamically, and so I'll need to be able to add multiple elements with escaped content programmatically.

Comment: You could always just escape the HTML separately, a la http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020714/escape-html-using-jquery etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create a dummy element to hold the result of `.text()` which can then be appended to  your destination element:

```
$('<div/>').text('your <span>html</span> string').appendTo(...);
```

Comment: Good idea.  I'll use this with one slight modification - `$('<div/>').text('your <span>html</span> string').html();`.  That way  I don't get the actual dummy element in with the text.

Comment: As a side note, you could also use `document.createTextNode` and append that.

Answer (score 8):

As I have tried many ways, I think the following method is the cleanest way to add text to whatever node you want.
no stock tag needed, only plain text, which will help to avoid potential problems

```
$(document.createTextNode("SomePlainText")).appendTo(p);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use

```
$(whatever).text($(whatever).text() + whatever_you_want_to_append);
```

EDIT for the fiddle in my comment, try this:

```
for ( /* some looping parameters */ ) {
    $('<li></li>') // create an li
        .text(stringWithHtml) // pass it the text, as text not html
        .appendTo('#thisIsWhatINeed'); // append it where you want it
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qtZ7u/4/)

Comment: Note that `.text` also accepts a function: `$(whatever).text(function(i, txt) { return txt + foo;});`

Comment: Yes, this will work for a single addition.  However, I need to be able  to append multiple elements with escape content in a loop - see my edit.

Comment: @friendlycello: There is no reason why the code I provided could not be used within a loop or what have you.

Comment: @DragoonWraith: Sorry, I was unclear.  Here's what I mean - [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/friendlycello/qtZ7u/)

Comment: @friendlycello: Ah, that's a bit different. See updated answer. Fairly similar to João's now.

Comment: @DragoonWraith: I like that.  A little cleaner than what I'm doing now.  Thanks.