# jQuery append pure text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to append the text `<b>text</b>` to an element as a child without changing it into HTML.

`append('<b>text</b>')` gives bold content `text`, but I want the text to be `<b>text</b>`.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957529/append-html-escaped-text-jquery

Comment: I dont understand the fuzz -> http://jsfiddle.net/5aF6a/ why all those mysterious alternative solutions?

Comment: @davidkonrad That’s not appending, that’s replacing.

Comment: @davidkonrad Because I need to create a new element, rather than change the parent as you did in the example

Comment: oh yes, but isnt that basically the same deal -> `$('<p></p>').text('<b>test</b>').appendTo('#test')` ?? no need for creating a native TextNode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Append a text node:

```
.append(document.createTextNode('<b>text</b>'));
```

Comment: But I need the new node to be `<p>`

Comment: @Ovilia You should include your current markup and your desired markup in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to mix up native js to accomplish this,

```
var node = document.createTextNode("<b>test</b>");
$('element')[0].appendChild(node);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MVjkb/)