# jQuery ajax code loading scripts as text, but some of the code is being processed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am working on a block of code and it is doing something funny.  I wrote this for a site that I am working on to load a url from an XML file and insert the code from a server side file into the pre tag as a way of showing the code I developed for a class.  This block works just fine for both Python and MEL scripts, but when I tried to load the scripts for the site itself (javascript and xml) which I developed as a side project for the class, it tries to evaluate parts of it.  Specifically, the HTML tags tags that are inside of the code.  I am unsure of how to stop this from happening.  It isn't direly important that I have this, I would just like to show off the work that I did that was above and beyond the rest of the class for potential future employers.  I am really proud of the site as it sits.

```
id = $(this).attr("id");
$("#"+location+"_code").append("<a href='"+$(this).attr("src")+"' class='download' download/><dt>"+$(this).attr("title")+"</dt><dd><pre id='"+id+"'></pre></dd>");
$.ajax({
    url:$(this).attr('src'),
    dataType: "text",
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
        $("#"+id).append(data);
    }
});
```

How do I prevent the browser from actually processing the text as anything but text?  I really was hoping that this would just display the code as a straight string.  I thought about using a textarea instead of a pre, but that just caused a host of other issues that I didn't feel like dealing with.  Any suggestions?

Comment: See the solution of this question, it may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957529/append-html-escaped-text-jquery

Comment: You really shouldn't use async false

Comment: @DelightedD0d I tried to use asychronous and it did not load them in the right order from the files and processed my success function after all of the other javascript is completed.  With the ASYNC off it worked.  If you can help me with that problem, I will turn it back on.

Comment: Are these file you're getting all in one directory or are these all just random links?

Answer (score 1):

You need to HTML encode your result so it displays as text. Try this:

```
var $result = $('<div/>').text(data);
$('#' + id).append($result);
```