# jQuery find and sanitize

Tags: jquery, htmlspecialchars

I am needing to, on form submit, look at a certain textarea being submitted and check for all `<code>` tags. Then take everything between a `<code>` tag set and run this function on this function on it:

```
function escapeHtml(unsafe) {
return unsafe
    .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
    .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
    .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
    .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
    .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
}
```

I was thinking of using :

```
$("code").each(function (){ });
```

Will that work? I'm testing it now but would like to know if there is a better way.

Comment: Are these code tags inside the textarea?

Comment: Not like this: `<textarea><code></code></textarea>`
But in the textarea you view on a website I'd be typing the tags in there.

Answer (score 0):

Look at same questions [Fastest method to escape HTML tags as HTML entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499078/fastest-method-to-escape-html-tags-as-html-entities) OR [Escape HTML using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020714/escape-html-using-jquery). You can choose answer from one of them.