# Html Tag in textbox/input text

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

When I input some html tag like `< b>` or `< test>` (without the space after "<") in my TextBoxes, When I submit the form I got the issue:

> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server.

The status code returned from the server was: 500

I don't want to set the "ValidateRequest" false, because of security problems.

I thought in make some kind of javascript function inserting a space after "<", this could work...I guess.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can escape your input using javascript before posting it back.

See existing answers:

- [Escaping HTML strings with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery)
- [Escape HTML using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020714/escape-html-using-jquery)
- [Fastest method to escape HTML tags as HTML entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499078/fastest-method-to-escape-html-tags-as-html-entities)

On the c# side use [`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx) to decode your text back.

Answer (score 1):

You can escape/unescape your html content using JavaScript (jQuery) as shown below:

```
<script>
    function htmlEncode(value) {
        return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
    }

    function htmlDecode(value) {
        return $('<div/>').html(value).text();
    }
</script>
```