# JQuery - Add regular HTML along with escaped HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-escape-characters

I store some data in firebase (which can be retrieved in the client), and then, I add it to the HTML using JQuery. This is easy - I just prepend the data to the DOM element. However, the issue is, this raw code will be vulnerable to attacks, so I need to properly escape the data taken from the database before adding it to the HTML. I thought the following code would do the job:

```
function escapeHTML(text) {
  var map = {
    '&': '&amp;',
    '<': '&lt;',
    '>': '&gt;',
    '"': '&quot;',
    "'": '&#039;'
  };
  return text.replace(/[&<>"']/g, function(m) { return map[m]; });
}

$('#element').prepend('<h1>Heading</h1><p>' + escapeHTML(data) + '</p>');
```

When I test this code, by making the value of data something like `<script>alert('This should not work');</script>`, I thought that it would just add this text to the `<p></p>` tags, without executing the JS, but it actually ran the code.

I understand that using `$('#element').text()` will escape the text for me, but I don't want everything to get escaped - I still want to add the `<h1></h1>` and `<p></p>` tags, I just need the variable "data" to be escaped. I saw a couple of StackOverflow posts on similar topics, but none of them seem to address this issue - [post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234773/can-i-escape-html-special-chars-in-javascript), [post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery), [post 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020714/escape-html-using-jquery).

Comment: XSS is more than just <script> tags

Comment: @epascarello what do you mean? Isn't that the only way to run inserted JS code?

Comment: no, there are more ways to do it.

Comment: @epascarello ook. Could you please give me an example or some links?

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)

Comment: Why don't you just ban inline javascript for the page?

Comment: Here's the link to get started https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/disable-inline-javascript-for-security/

Comment: You should never trust data coming from the client, you should generate or validate it on the server.

Comment: @Barmar I also tried that - I actually tried escaping the HTML in the server itself, but weirdly enough, it had no effect - when I added the escaped HTML to the DOM, it still ran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the code in your question didn't work is because all the entities like `&amp;` in the Javascript are parsed as the characters they represent when the JS in the HTML is parsed. It would work if you put the code in an external `.js` file, since that's not parsed as HTML. Or you could double-encode them:

```
  var map = {
    '&': '&amp;amp;',
    '<': '&amp;lt;',
    '>': '&amp;gt;',
    '"': '&amp;quot;',
    "'": '&amp;#039;'
  };
```

But a better way is to create the `<h1>` and `<p>` elements separately, and put the escaped text in the paragraph using a jQuery method.

```js
const data = '<scr' + 'ipt>alert("foo");</scr' + 'ipt>';

$("#element").prepend("<h1>Heading</h1>", $("<p>", {text: data}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="element"></div>
```

If you want to fill in data attributes, you can do it similarly:

```
$("#element").prepend($("<div>", {
    data: {
        attr: data,
        another: someMoreData
    },
    text: "hello world"
}));
```

Comment: doubt this would meet the OPs needs if the content contains tags like bold and such. Maybe it is plain text and would be fine....

Comment: Why do you say that?

Comment: @Barmar I am actually adding the data from firebase like this: `$('#element').prepend('<div data-attr="'+data+'" data-another="'+someMoreData+'">hello world</div>')`. So, I don't know how to use your JQuery method... Also, this is already in an external JS file, and even if it wasn't, I don't think it would get parsed as HTML - it's in a string. But this is probably not the cause of my issue. However, your double escaping method worked like a charm! Thanks a lot! I can't upvote you yet though, as my rep is too low

Comment: I've added code that shows how to fill in the data attributes using the object method.